# Ansible first hostname of groups

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am not sure on how to find the first ansible hostname from group_names. Could you kindly advise me on how to do it?

hosts

```
[webservers]
server1
server2
server3

[webserver-el7]
server4
server5
server6
```

And i have 2 different playbook for each host groups

playbook1.yml

```
- name: deploy app
  hosts: webservers
  serial: 8
  roles:
    - roles1
```

playbook2.yml

```
- name: deploy app
  hosts: webservers-el7
  serial: 8
  roles:
    - roles1
```

the problem is that i have delegate task to first host of each group. previously i only used webservers group, so it was much easier by using the task below

```
- name: syncing web files to {{ version_dir }}
  synchronize:
    src: "{{ build_dir }}"
    dest: "{{ version_dir }}"
    rsync_timeout: 60
  delegate_to: "{{ groups.webservers | first }}"
```

If i have 2 different group_names, how can i select the first one of each group? so it can be more dynamic

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want the first host of current play to be a kind of master host to sync from, I'd recommend another approach: use one of `play_hosts` or `ansible_play_hosts` (depending on your Ansible version) variables. See [magic variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts).
Like `delegate_to: "{{ play_hosts | first }}"`.

The thing is when you say `hosts: webservers-el7` to Ansible `webservers-el7` is a pattern here. Ansible search for hosts to match this pattern and feed them into Play. You may have written `webservers-el*` as well. So inside Play you don't have any variable that will tell you *"I'm running this Play on hosts from group webserver-el7..."*. You may only make some guess work analyzing `group_names` and `groups` magic variables. But this become clumsy when you have one host in several groups.

For hosts in single group only, you may try: `groups[group_names | first] | first`

Comment: Just tried the play hosts and it would work perfectly unless i was not using serial deployment. i would like to use the master host to sync from but on the next serial play, the first play_hosts will change again. currently my hosts will only belong to single group only. do you know how to get the first hostname from group_names? i already tried several variable but still no luck

Comment: Updated answer with example. Also you may consider to use Ansible 2.2+ with `ansible_play_hosts` – it contains full lists for each serial run.

Comment: Nice. it works really well. ansible_play_hosts would works too. Thanks a lot for your ansible expertise

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov: How can we get second hostname of group

Answer (score 1):

To get any element from group, use `group[group_name][0...n]`.

This will get the first element from the group.

```yaml
- debug: msg="{{ groups['group_name'][0] }}"
```